# How to use 'if then' expressions to generate a sentence that is word by word pieced together to generate a whole sentence

Tags: c, xcode

I am working through some code wherein I am wanting to piece (word by word) variations of the following sentence together, but I am working through my 'if' and 'else if' usage so only this please :

```
You are in a twisting little maze of passages, all different.
```

In fact, there is a total of 12 sentences I am trying to generate:

```
        You are in a twisting little maze of passages, all different.
        You are in a little twisting maze of passages, all different.
        You are in a twisty little maze of passages, all different.
        You are in a little twisty maze of passages, all different.
        You are in a little maze of twisting passages, all different.
        You are in a little maze of twisty passages, all different.
        You are in a twisting maze of little passages, all different.
        You are in a twisty maze of little passages, all different.
        You are in a maze of twisting little passages, all different.
        You are in a maze of little twisting passages, all different.
        You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all different.
        You are in a maze of little twisty passages, all different.
```

The variables I am using are as follows:

```
1) int little  /  2) int twist  /  3) int twisting   / 4) int before
```

Their function is as follows:

1. The first property to consider in the sentences above is whether the adjective “little” comes before (i.e., modifies) the noun “maze”, or comes before the noun “passages”.  In other words, what is it that is little, the maze or the passages?  This flag will be called “little”.  It is the first argument of the function.  If the value of “little” is 0, then “little” comes before “maze”, as in the first six sentences above.  If the value of “little” is 1, then “little” comes before “passages”, as in the last six sentences above.
2. The second property is similar to the first property.  The property is whether the twist adjective (either “twisty” or “twisting”) comes before the noun “maze” or before the noun “passages”.  This flag will be called “twist”.  It is the second argument of the function.  If the value of “twist” is 0, then the twist adjective comes before “maze”.  If the value of “twist” is 1, then the twist adjective comes before “passages”.
3. The third property is whether the twist adjective is “twisty” or “twisting”.  This flag will be called “twisting”.  It is the third argument of the function.  If the value of “twisting” is 0, then the twist adjective is “twisty”.  If the value of “twisting” is 1, then the twist adjective is “twisting”.
4. The fourth property is whether adjective “little” comes before or after the twist adjective, if both adjectives modify the same noun.  This flag will be called “before”.  It is the fourth argument of the function.  If the value of “before” is 0, then “little” comes after the twist adjective.  If the value of “before” is 1, then “little” comes before the twist adjective.  When the two adjectives do not come before the same noun, this flag does not make any difference, and this is why there are only twelve distinct sentences.

I have the following line of thinking:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mazesentence(int little, int twist, int twisting, int before)
{
    
    printf("You are in a ");
    
    
    if(little == 0 && twist == 0)
    {
        if(before == 0)
        {
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1);
                printf("twisting ");
            printf("little ");
        }
        else if(before == 1)
            printf("little ");
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1);
                printf("twisting ");
        printf("of maze ");
    }
           
    
    if(little == 1 && twist == 1)
    {
        if(before == 0)
        {
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1);
                printf("twisting ");
            printf("little");
        }
        else if(before == 1)
            printf("little ");
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1);
                printf("twisting ");
        printf("passages");
    }
        
    printf("passages, all different.\n");

    return;
}

int main( )
{
    mazesentence(0, 0, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 1, 1);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 0, 1);
    mazesentence(0, 1, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(0, 1, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 0, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 0, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 1, 1);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 0, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the output is the following:

```
You are in a twisting little twisting of maze passages, all different.
You are in a little twisting of maze passages, all different.
You are in a twisty twisting little twisty twisting of maze passages, all different.
You are in a little twisty twisting of maze passages, all different.
You are in a passages, all different.
You are in a passages, all different.
You are in a passages, all different.
You are in a passages, all different.
You are in a twisting littletwisting passagespassages, all different.
You are in a little twisting passagespassages, all different.
You are in a twisty twisting littletwisty twisting passagespassages, all different.
You are in a little twisty twisting passagespassages, all different.
```

These 12 sentences need to match the above mentioned 12 sentences. The first sentence is almost the same with the exception of an extra 'twisting'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well try working through your logic. For example, what is it supposed to do if `little == 0` and `twist == 1`? You might make this code easier to read and debug if you used arrays instead of all these `if()` statements.

Comment: Using proper `{` `}` brackets formatting would also help (and likely solve the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in the code and others in the logic:

1. The 'else if' doesn't do anything because of the '**;**', the printf after it will occur every time.

   ```
   else if(twisting == 1);
     printf("twisting ");
   ```

   This is the correct way to use it:

   ```
   else if(twisting == 1)
     printf("twisting ");
   ```
2. There are also some problems with the logic, so there will be time when it will do nothing.

I modified your code a little bit and it is working:

```
void mazesentence(int little, int twist, int twisting, int before)
{

printf("You are in a ");


if(twist == 0)
{
    if(before == 0){
        if (twisting == 0){
            printf("twisty ");
        } else if (twisting == 1){
            printf("twisting ");
        }
        if(little == 0){
            printf("little ");  
        }
    }else if(before == 1){
        if(little == 0){
            printf("little ");  
        }
        if(twisting == 0)
            printf("twisty ");
        else if(twisting == 1)
            printf("twisting ");
    }
    printf("maze of ");
    if(little == 1){
        printf("little ");
    }
}else if(twist == 1){
    
    if(little == 0){
        printf("little maze of ");
        if(before == 1){
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1)
                printf("twisting ");
        }
    }else if(little == 1){
        printf("maze of ");
        if(before == 1){
            printf("little ");  
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1)
                printf("twisting ");
        }else if(before == 0){
            if(twisting == 0)
                printf("twisty ");
            else if(twisting == 1)
                printf("twisting ");
            printf("little ");  
        }
    }
}
    
printf("passages, all different.\n");

return;
}

int main( )
{
    mazesentence(0, 0, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 1, 1);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(0, 0, 0, 1);
    mazesentence(0, 1, 1, 1);
    mazesentence(0, 1, 0, 1);
    mazesentence(1, 0, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 0, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 1, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 1, 1);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 0, 0);
    mazesentence(1, 1, 0, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling with it for hours.